# Do I need a form to POST data?

Tags: ajax, django

T'm planning to a Ajax calls to post some data. The data Im going to post is a simple string containing a IP that will be validated against regular expression.

I can do in Javascript but the Python socket module does it very simple..

Question:

1. Do i always need a form to POST a request? I just need to pass a string?

Answer (score 1):

You might just perform a normal asynchronous post as you'd do with Javascript or jQuery for a certain URL with your data.

For doing so with javascript, just create a XMLHttpRequest with whatever you have and send it.
With jQuery is even simpler.

jQuery:

```
$.post('/your_url' {
    your_item: value
    other_item: value2,

},
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

edit:
The answer is **no**. Just handle the result in a view anyway.